# Django edits rows instead of adding a new one

Tags: python, django

Is there any reason why code like this would edit the only row from a table instead of creating a new one?

```
newStudent = Student(name=var.name,
                     mark=var.mark,
                     year=newyear)
newStudent.save()
```

**Explanation:**

I am working on student records. This view is called when I'm updating a student's information. 
`var.name` is the student's name before the edit and `var.mark` is his mark before the edit. `newyear` is the year I'm adding this information for.

This view is called every year (i.e. a student has a new name and mark every year). After these lines, I proceed to edit the student's current year information.

**The problem:**

This code edits the only row from the Student table in the database instead of adding a new one.

Comment: Might be it is happen because of you provide same record to `Student()`

Comment: why do you mean by the same record? I'm 100% positive ```year``` is changing, since this is how I figured out the view edits records instead of adding new ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are desiring object creation, use django's Model manager methods to create your object, i.e:

```
Student.objects.create(name=var.name, mark=var.mark, year=newyear)
```

This will ensure creation explicitly instead of fetching rows with existing values.

Comment: You're right. Apparently, I had a problem with primary keys that prevented the view from creating new records. I'll mark your answer correct in 6 minutes. (You can accept an answer in 6 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

If you use existing primary key when you create object, you can update your object.

```
student =  Student(name=var.name,
                     mark=var.mark,
                     year=newyear) 
student.save() # this means create new object



student =  Student(pk=existed_pk,name=var.name,
                     mark=var.mark,
                     year=newyear) 
student.save() # this means update student record which has existed_pk pk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update_or_create` method, a convenience method for updating your object with the given name, creating a new one if necessary. The defaults is a dictionary of (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

```
 obj, created = Student.objects.update_or_create(name=var.name, defaults={mark=var.mark, year=newyear})
```

Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the created or updated object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.